# Rendering two partials with a form using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering a partial that renders a form, using ajax (I can't just render the form directly). Posting a comment works fine when I'm rendering the form without ajax but with ajax it seems the partial can't access the @post variable.

```
<%= link_to "Render form", submit_comment_path, :remote => true  %>

<div id="form">
</div>
```

I have a submit_comment.js file that looks like this:

```
$("#form").html("<%= j render(partial: 'comment_partial', locals: {post: @post}) %>");
```

The comment_partial view:

```
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

The form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [post, Comment.new] %>

...
```

The submit_comment_path route:

```
 get  '/submit_comment', to: 'posts#submit_comment', as: :submit_comment
```

The posts controller (it's being rendered on the show page):

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])    
end

def submit_comment
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
 end
end
```

and the comments controller:

```
def create
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

If I try to post a new comment it gives me a routing error and takes me to `/posts//comment`. Putting `post.id` in the comment_partial gives me an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big piece of the puzzle is understanding that instance variables (@post in this instance) disappear as soon as the Controller renders anything.

You correctly assign @post when you render the show page:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])    
end
```

However, @post disappears the second that **show.html.erb** is done rendering. When you click on the link to hit the submit comment method, no @post is getting created...

```
def submit_comment
 # No instance variables here! :(
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
 end
end
```

Which means that the **submit_comment.js** file has no idea which post to be generating a form for.

However, it's not as simple as just throwing another Post.find(params[:id]) into the submit_comment method. You need to:

1. Define a route that relies on post id
2. Change the link in **show.html.erb** to include a specific @post.id
3. *Then* find the corresponding post to create a comment for.

It might look something like this...

**routes.rb**

```
...
resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'submit_comment'
  end
end
...
```

Read up on member routes [at the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). There are other ways of accomplishing a similar route.

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Render form", submit_comment_post_url(@post), :remote => true  %>
```

Note that the Rails default url helper is different than the one you've got, if you use member routes.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def submit_comment
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Hope that helps! Happy form-ing!

Comment: You bet! So glad I could help!